# How to update the crontab and check if its running correctly?

Tags: cron

I've modified the crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and added a cron for a script to run every minute so I can test if it works:

```
1 * * * * /scripts/backup-script.sh > /scripts/backup-script.logs
```

Afterwards, I tried to restart the cron service to restart the server but the cron doesn't seem to be working, I tried to use:

```
crontab -l
```

and it appears to have the old content as if I didnt even modify it. However, going into crontab -e does show the updated content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your script run every minute your cron record must be:

```
* * * * * /scripts/backup-script.sh > /scripts/backup-script.logs
```

What you enter will run every 1st minute every hour

And if you add record via `crontab` command you do not need to touch `cron` daemon

To see the cron record you add with `sudo crontab -e` you must check it with command `sudo crontab -l`. Otherwise you list `cron` record of different user

Comment: I was modifying the crontab with sudo and looking at the list without sudo, thanks a bunch.